# Ember Model get is not a function

Tags: ember.js

Why sometimes in setup controller on my product route, model.get('property') works and other times I have to retrieve properties with model.property

It throws an error

```
model.get( is not a function...
```

Why is this happening, clues?

Details :

Product Route -

```
model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('product', params.product_id);
},

setupController: function(controller, model){
    this._super(controller, model);

    var type = model.get('publisher').get('entity_type');
}
```

Index Route -

```
model: function(params){
    return Ember.RSVP.Promise.all([
        this.store.find('groupedItem', { group_code: 'HOME', position : 1 }),
        this.store.find('groupedItem', { group_code: 'HOME', position : 2 }),

    ])
}
```

Comment: What's your model hook look like?

Comment: Can you also post the part where you're calling model.get()? You posted the `setupController` for a different route.

Comment: Problem seems to be with POJOs, I don't know exactly when do I get a POJO from Ember Data local store, so I ended up retrieving values from model with Ember.get(model, 'attribute')

Comment: I already fix my issue temporary, but would like to know why is this behaviour...

Answer (score 1):

You're calling an asynchronous method in your `setupController` hook which Ember isn't expecting. You're probably trying to call `model.get()` before you've actually placed the model on the controller. That kind of asynchronous operation should be happening in the `model()` hook, not in the `setupController()` hook.

```
model: function() {
    return Ember.RSVP.Promise.all([
        this.store.find('groupedItem', { group_code: 'HOME', position : 1 }),
        this.store.find('groupedItem', { group_code: 'HOME', position : 2 })
    ]);
},

// This is actually the default behavior of this method
// So you don't have to override it if you don't want to
setupController: function(controller, model) {
    // The `model` is your `values`
    controller.set('model', model);
}
```

Comment: thnx for the advice, but do you know why sometimes Ember data returns POJO and sometimes an Ember Object?

Comment: Ember Data would always return an Ember object unless you've overridden something. Can you show an example of code that doesn't return one?

Comment: `RSVP.Promise` returns POJOs for `all` `hash` etc

Comment: That's not really Ember Data. RSVP is just an [ES6 Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) polyfill. EDIT: I thought you were OP. Obviously you know that. :p